# Linked lists - Additional variable printed

Tags: c, linked-list, output

I wanted to read friends birthday into the list and display it. But I am getting additional output to my print function. I thought that those might be addresses of the empty list, but I have no idea where is the mistake in my code that I am getting it printed.

[image]

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    struct Node * head = NULL;
    head = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));



    push(&head);
    push(&head);
    printList(head);

    free(head);

}


void printList(struct Node* read)
{
    while (read != NULL) {
        printf(" %d.%d %s \n", read->day, read->month, read->name);
        read = read->next;
    }
}

void push(struct Node** head)
{
    struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    int day, month;
    char name[256];

    printf("Day of birth: ");
    scanf("%d", &day);
    newNode->day  = day;
    printf("Month of birth: ");
    scanf("%d", &month);
    newNode->month  = month;
    printf("Friend's name: ");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    strcpy(newNode->name, name);

    newNode->next = (*head);
    (*head) = newNode;
}
```

Comment: `head = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));` seems odd, since you never write anything into that node. What happens when you remove that line and keep it a null pointer?

Comment: If you want to free the list, you need a loop and a temporary `Node *` variable to free each node.

Comment: The junk numbers being printed are from the `head` node allocated by `main`, which ends up at the end of the list, and is also likely to contain an invalid `next` pointer. As @UnholySheep indicated, you do not need to allocate a node in `main`, just leave `head` set to `NULL` before the first call to `push`.

Comment: The junk you see is coming from the uninitialized node that you allocate at the top of `main`.  Delete all of that.  All you need is `head = NULL;` which you already had.  Also, when you go to free the list, you're only freeing the first element, so you have a memory leak.  You need to walk the entire list, freeing each node in turn (but not before extracting the `next` link for the next iteration of your loop).